# Linear differential equation involving matrices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 9 & 2 \\ 1 & 8 \end{pmatrix}.$
>   Find the general solution $\mathbf{y}(t)$ of the system of
>   differential equations $\displaystyle \frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt} =
>  \mathbf{Ay}$:  $$\begin{cases} \frac{dy_1}{dt} = 9y_1+2y_2  \\ \frac{dy_2}{dt} =
>  y_1+8y_2  \end{cases}$$
>
> and find the unique solution satisfying $y_1(0) = 1$ and $y_2(0) =
>  5$.

I've shown that the solution is of the form $\mathbf{y} = ke^{\mathbf{A}t}$, where $k \in \mathbb{R}$. But I don't know how to get the given equations. I've also calculated the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ as $\lambda = 7,10$. But I cannot proceed further.

Comment: You should know how to compute $e^{t\mathbf A}$ if you know the eigenvalues *and eigenvectors* of $\mathbf A$. If not, go read about it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've tried to read around online, but while I've found the fact that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ is an eigenvector then $e^{t\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{v} = e^{\lambda t} \mathbf{v}$ I couldn't find the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this.  You say that you have found that the 7 and 10.  Those are distinct so this matrix is "diagonalizable".  That means that if P is the matrix formed by the Eigen**vectors** of the matrix then $P^{-1}AP= \begin{pmatrix}7 & 0 \\ 0 & 10\end{pmatrix}$ which, with corresponding variables called $y_1'$ and $y_2'$, corresponds to the "uncoupled" equations $dy_1'/dt= 7y_1'$ and $dy_2'/dt= 10y_2$. After finding those functions, go back to $y_1$ and $y_2$ by using $P^{-1}$.

Personally, I would use a more "basic" method.  Differentiate the first equation **again** to get $\frac{d^2y_1}{dt^2}= 9\frac{dy_1}{dx}+ 2\frac{dy_2}{dx}$.  Replace $\frac{dy_2}{dx}$ in that from the other equation, $\frac{dy_2}{dt}= y_1+ 8y_2$, to get $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}= 9\frac{dy_1}{dt}+ 2(y_1+ 8y_2)= 9\frac{dy_1}{dt}+ 2y_1+ 16y_2= 0$.  Finally, from $\frac{dy_1}{dt}= 9y_1+ 2y_2$, $2y_2= \frac{dy_1}{dt}- 9y_1$ so $16y_2= 8\frac{dy_1}{dt}- 72y_1$ so the equation $\frac{d^2y_1}{dt^2}= 9\frac{dy_1}{dt}+ 2y_1+ 8\frac{dy_1}{dt}- 72y_1= 17\frac{dy_1}{dt}- 71y_1= 0$ (Better check my arithmetic).  Once you have found $y_1$ from that second order differential equation (so two arbitrary constants) you can fine $y_2$ from $2y_2= \frac{dy_1}{dt}- 9y_1$.